# Error output from Xcode build after upgrading Flutter dependencies

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I recently upgraded dependencies version for my Flutter app. Since then I am continuously getting error to run iOS build on emulator and iOS device both. I am getting following error:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[88852]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f68cab90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1047e02c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[88852]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f68cabe0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1047e0318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    AssertMacros: amdErr = AMDeviceConnect(tmpDevice) == 0 ,  file: /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MobileDevice/MobileDevice-1368.60.4/Source/AMDevicePowerAssertion.c, line: 224, value: -402653052
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

I tried different solutions available around me but still it is creating issue. Here is my dependencies from .yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4

  http: ^0.13.4
  http_interceptor: ^1.0.2
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.1.1
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  flutter_bloc: ^4.0.1

  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.7
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
  firebase_remote_config: ^2.0.0

  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  geolocator: ^8.1.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.18
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.1.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  map_launcher: ^2.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  email_validator: '^1.0.6'
  flutter_verification_code: ^1.1.2+1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+7
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0
  query_params: ^0.6.1
  mailto: ^2.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.2.0
  device_info_plus: ^3.2.1
  timezone: ^0.8.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.3
  characters: ^1.2.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
  sign_in_apple: ^2.0.0
  device_calendar: ^4.1.0
  cron: ^0.4.0
  package_info_plus: ^1.3.0
#  flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6
  local_auth: ^1.1.10
```

Comment: Goodday... you can try deleting the podfile.lock and enter command in ios folder **pod cache clean --all** after that do a **pod install** again

Comment: I have tried that one but it's not working.

Comment: The xcode report seems very vague... how about try cleaning your xcode at the meantime... you can follow this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13QubFwmDoc and try rebuilding your app after this...